# Debug logging VB.net

Tags: vb.net, debugging, logging

I'm trying to create a Debug log for my application, and I'd like to document everything to the log.

- %TimeStamp% - Loaded main form
- %TimeStamp% - Loaded Settings
- %TimeStamp% - Entered Ready state
  etc.

I've got a function that creates a folder to house the debug log, and creates the debug file accordingly:

```
Dim DebugFile As String = String.Format(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\App\Debug_{0}.txt", DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))

    Public Sub Debug_File_Check()
        ' Set a variable to the My Documents path.
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\App\")) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\App\")
        End If
    End Sub
```

And a function that opens the debug file and writes a line to it:

```
Public Sub Debug()
    Using writer As New StreamWriter(DebugFile, True)
        If File.Exists(DebugFile) Then
            writer.WriteLine(%DEBUG MESSAEGE + " Occured at-- " & DateTime.Now)
        Else
            writer.WriteLine("Start Error Log for today")
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

My question is, how can I pass information from something like:

```
Private Sub FrmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Debug_File_Check()
    Debug("The form has loaded")
End Sub
```

Where it, on one line, will write the debug line to my debug.txt file?

---

I've never dealt with debug logging before, so not even sure if I'm on the write track.

Comment: I'd recommend using [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: So, log4net is great! Thanks a bunch for this tip! @Filburt

Comment: Always glad to help ;)